# How to crop a .png EncodedImage in BlackBerry while preserving transparency

Tags: blackberry

I have a single .png image with several icons on it (with transparent areas) and would like to crop individual icons from it. In Java ME it was rather straight-forward, but in BlackBerry I haven't found an equivalent. The [code here shows an example with a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682250/blackberry-cropping-image), however doing so paints the transparent areas with white color:

```
public Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap image, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics g = new Graphics(result);
    g.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, image, x, y);
    return result;
}
```

I need the same for an EncodedImage to keep the transparency, but `Graphics` constructor accepts only a `Bitmap`. Is there any other way to accomplish this? Thank you for any tips.

**UPDATE:**

Transparency can be preserved if you omit the intermediate Graphics object altogether, and set the ARGB data directly to the newly created Bitmap, like so:

```
public Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap image, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    int[] argbData = new int[width * height];
    image.getARGB(argbData, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
    result.setARGB(argbData, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Apparently there's no way to return a cropped image (from a larger image), while also keeping the transparency. I worked around this by passing the graphics context into my method, and drawing a subset from the larger image directly into the graphics context -- that way at least the transparency is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't try this code but it should give you the idea:

```
int[] argbData = new int[ width * height ];
image.getARGB(      argbData,
                    0,
                    width
                    x,
                    y,
                    width,
                    height);

Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics g = new Graphics(result);
g.drawARGB(argbData , 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

return result;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but the result is absolutely the same -- it does not preserve the transparency and draws white pixels where the transparent area should be. As it stands now, I still haven't found a way to crop an image from a larger image while keeping the transparent parts.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help but you can check this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Transparent-background-for-Bitmap/m-p/233113/message-uid/233113

Comment: Instead of creating a Graphics object, could you just do a result.setARGB(...) directly into the new Bitmap?

Comment: Thank you Marc, it worked when I set it directly into the new Bitmap!

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
g.setGlobalAlpha(0);
```

before

```
g.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, image, x, y);
```

or you can use

```
drawARGB(int[] data, int offset, int scanLength, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

which preserve the alpha in the destination image.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please provide an example of how the int[] data is obtained in the drawARGB(). Thank you!

Comment: Also, using g.setGlobalAlpha(0) does not work -- it paints the entire area with solid white color.